# Unable to scale Azure SQL database using a variable

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-sql-database

I am trying to do the following:

1. Capture the original Edition and RequestedServiceObjectiveName of an Azure sql database using the following PS script:

```
$OriginalScale= Get-AzSqlDatabase `
                    -ResourceGroupName "POC_Scale" `
                    -ServerName "scaledb" `
                    -DatabaseName "scaleME"
```

2.Scale up this database to a particular edition and tier using:

```
Set-AzSqlDatabase `
                    -ResourceGroupName "POC_Scale" `
                    -ServerName "scaledb" `
                    -DatabaseName "scaleME" `
            -Edition "Standard" `
            -RequestedServiceObjectiveName "S3" `
```

3.After deployment, scale it back to the original scale that I had captured prior to step 2 using:

```
Set-AzSqlDatabase `
                    -ResourceGroupName "POC_Scale" `
                    -ServerName "scaledb" `
                    -DatabaseName "scaleME" `
            -Edition "$OriginalScale.Edition" `
            -RequestedServiceObjectiveName "$OriginalScale.RequestedServiceObjectiveName" `
```

I get the following error:

[image: Error]

I have tried the following:

1. Tried to use single quotes around the -Edition and -RequestedServiceObjectName being passed in but I get the same error.
2. Checked that the $OriginalScale.Edition does indeed return "Standard". Also checked docs and found that .Edition is actually a string which should theoretically work.

Can someone please guide me on what I'm doing wrong here. Seems simple but not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quotes are the problem. Either don't use the quotes, or do it like this:

`-Edition "$($OriginalScale.Edition)"`

The syntax you're currently trying is ignoring the `.Edition` and only outputting the PSObject name.